# Unable to ssm into my EC2 instance due to full disk space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was copying huge files in my r5a.4xlarge ec2 instance. While copying I got an error message that the disk size is full so cannot copy further.

I closed that session and start another session using the command `aws ssm start-session --target <instance id>`

all I get is a message that -  `Starting session with SessionId: <sessionid>` and nothing happens.
Earlier it used to start the session very smoothly. 
Can anyone help? All I want to do is enter the instance and delete the copied files.

Comment: The issue got resolved the next day, there was some problem from the aws side. I got a mail regarding the down time.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly where the files are located, you can try using User Data to execute clean up on next restart: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

However it might not work, since cloud-init needs to create file on filesystem in order to function. In this case you can try detaching root volume, attaching it to another instance and cleaning it up from there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to delete the file with SSM Run Command?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/rc-console.html

You can use the existing AWS-RunShellScript (or AWS-RunPowerShellScript) to execute the CLI commands to delete the files you wish to delete.